Running vite preview in a gitlab runner's background
I have a docker container with a gitlab runner and a stage named "preview" in it. It should run a npm run serve command and end the pipeline. Npm run serve script contains following code: ./node_modules/.bin/tsc && vite build && ./node_modules/.bin/vite preview --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4173. It works and preview starts, but pipeline remains unfinished because of running process.
I tried to add '&' at the end of command, but it didn't help.
So how can I run vite preview in a background and end the pipeline?

Depending on how long you want that preview to be available, you can try the following:
timeout 30 <your_command_here>

E.g.,
timeout 30 ./node_modules/.bin/tsc && vite build && ./node_modules/.bin/vite preview --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4173

This will end your preview after 30 seconds. Note that a pipeline always has a timeout and will never run endlessly. This means you can also modify the pipeline timeout in the Gitlab UI under Settings - CI/CD - timeout. This is usually set to 1h.
